# R: Grouped rolling window linear regression with rollapply and ddply

Tags: r, plyr, rollapply

I have a data set with several grouping variables on which I want to run a rolling window linear regression. The ultimate goals is to extract the 10 linear regressions with the lowest slopes and average them together to provide a mean minimum rate of change. I have found examples using rollapply to calculate rolling window linear regressions, but I have the added complication that I would like to apply these linear regressions to groups within the data set.

Here is a sample data set and my current code which is close and isn't quite working.

```
dat<-data.frame(w=c(rep(1,27), rep(2,27),rep(3,27)), z=c(rep(c(1,2,3),27)), 
x=c(rep(seq(1,27),3)), y=c(rnorm(27,10,3), rnorm(27,3,2.2), rnorm(27, 6,1.3)))
```

where w and z are two grouping variables and x and y are the regression terms.

From my internet searches here is aR basic rolling window linear regression code where the window size is 6, sequential regressions are separated by 3 data points and I am extracting only the slope coef(lm...)[2]

```
library(zoo)    
slopeData<-rollapply(zoo(dat), width=6, function(Z) { 
coef(lm(formula=y~x, data = as.data.frame(Z), na.rm=T))[2]
}, by = 3, by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

Now I wish to apply this rolling window regression to the groups specified by the two grouping variables w and z. So I tried something like this using ddply from plyr package. First I try to rewrite the code above as a function.

```
rolled<-function(df) {
    rollapply(zoo(df), width=6, function(Z) { 
    coef(lm(formula=y~x, data = as.data.frame(Z), na.rm=T))[2]
    }, by = 3, by.column=FALSE, align="right")
}
```

And then run apply that function using ddply

```
groupedSlope <- ddply(dat, .(w,z), function(d) rolled(d))
```

This, however, doesn't work as I get a series of warnings and errors. I imagine that some of the errors may relate to the combining of zoo formats and data frames and this becomes overly complicated. Its what I have been working on so far, but 
does anyone know of a means of getting grouped, rolling window linear regressions, potentially simpler than this method?

Thanks for any assistance,
Nate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `rollapply` works on data frames too so it is not necessary to convert `df` to zoo.

2) `lm` uses `na.action`, not `na.rm`, and its default is `na.omit` so we can just drop this argument.

3) `rollapplyr` is a more concise way to write `rollapply(..., align = "right")`.

Assuming that `rolled` otherwise does what you want and incorporating these changes into `rolled`, the `ddply` statement in the question should work or we could use `by` from the base of R which we show below:

```
rolled <- function(df) {
    rollapplyr(df, width = 6, function(m) { 
          coef(lm(formula = y ~ x, data = as.data.frame(m)))[2]
       }, by = 3, by.column = FALSE
   )
}
do.call("rbind", by(dat, dat[c("w", "z")], rolled))
```

Comment: This code works well for the sample data that I provided. Thank you. However, I now have issues when I try to extend this to my actual dataset. As this answer nicely address my original questions I accepted it, but I have posted a new question here ...(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332566/r-rollapplyr-and-lm-factor-error-does-rollapplyr-change-variable-class) regarding my new challenges. If you have additional insights I'd appreciate them.